# My method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java

I just started programming in Java so I'm still pretty much a noob. I tried to check if a sentence contains a specific word. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void run(String[] args)  {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print( "Please provide a string" );
        String str1 = sc.next();

        if (str1.contains("Test")) {
            System.out.println("V");
        } else {
            System.out.println("X");
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
}
```

When I try to test this I get the following error:

```
The method run(String[]) in the type Test is not applicable 
for the arguments (String)
```

I really don't have any idea how to fix this, so I would really appreciate it if someone has a hint/tip for me on how to fix this

Comment: Change method name from "run" to "main". ,My interest is how did you get the code from. You using any IDE or from internet?

Comment: The best solution to this *and your future issues* is to check the intro to Java tutorials, and you can find them here: [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). Good luck and much success on your coding adventure!

Comment: I got it from one of the slides of the course I'm following. They also provided a test with the following lines: char output = Test.run("");. So that made me guess that I had to use run instead of main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, that would probably be your `main` method, the primary entry point of a Java program for the Java Virtual Machine.

Also, be sure that what parameters are being passed to a method are what it expects: you can't pass just a string, i.e. " ", to a method expecting a string array, i.e. ["", "", ""].